# waitForElementVisible fails the test even though element when third argument set to false

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have the following function that I am using in nightwatch.js

```
this.browser.waitForElementVisible(this.element.ims.terms.tos, 30000, false, function (result) {
```

Even when the third argument is set to false, waitForElementVisible still fails the tests.

What should I be doing to wait to see if an element is visible, and if it is do something?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post whole code block,may be the next lines made the test crashed.

You can try this one to debug

```
browser.pause(10000);
browser.verify.visible(this.element.ims.terms.tos);
browser.pause(10000);
```